# how do you give a custom shield or banner a name with commands and yet keep the design on it,

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying lots from

```
/give @p minecraft:banner 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:drs,Color:0},{Pattern:dls,Color:0},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ms,Color:11},{Pattern:cs,Color:15},{Pattern:mc,Color:11},{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:hhb,Color:14},{Pattern:bts,Color:1},{Pattern:tt,Color:1},{Pattern:mr,Color:11}]}}
```

and

```
/give @p minecraft:shield 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:drs,Color:0},{Pattern:dls,Color:0},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ms,Color:11},{Pattern:cs,Color:15},{Pattern:mc,Color:11},{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:hhb,Color:14},{Pattern:bts,Color:1},{Pattern:tt,Color:1},{Pattern:mr,Color:11}]}}
```

but it never comes up with the name and design on it. How to do it right?

Comment: It works for me, did you put the command in a command block?

Answer (score 0):

To give a name to your shield or banner, first add `display:{}` before `BlockEntityTag:{}` separated by a comma. This deals with how the item is labeled. To get the name to display, add `Name:` and whatever name you want to use surrounded by quotes.

The JSON part of the command will now start with `{display:{Name:"My Custom Named Item"},` and should not interfere with your pattern (see result in screenshot).

[image]

Comment: I tried this: /give @p minecraft:shield 1 0 {display:{Name: "custom"}},{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:drs,Color:0},{Pattern:dls,Color:0},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ms,Color:11},{Pattern:cs,Color:15},{Pattern:mc,Color:11},{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:hhb,Color:14},{Pattern:bts,Color:1},{Pattern:tt,Color:1},{Pattern:mr,Color:11}]}}
 and it said that it had encountered multiple top tags

Comment: I then tried /give @p minecraft:shield 1 0 {display:{Name: "custom"}{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:drs,Color:0},{Pattern:dls,Color:0},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ms,Color:11},{Pattern:cs,Color:15},{Pattern:mc,Color:11},{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:hhb,Color:14},{Pattern:bts,Color:1},{Pattern:tt,Color:1},{Pattern:mr,Color:11}]}}}                       and that didnt work either! It said it was unable to locate name?value seperator for string: {BlockEntityTag:...............                onwards!

Comment: @Bounce01 Get rid of the second } after "Custom" (referring to your first comment)

Comment: that has unbalanced brackets

Comment: @Bounce01 Weird... try this then: `/give @p minecraft:banner 1 0 {display:{Name:"Custom"},BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:drs,Color:0},{Pattern:dls,Color:0},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ms,Color:11},{Pattern:cs,Color:15},{Pattern:mc,Color:11},{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:hhb,Color:14},{Pattern:bts,Color:1},{Pattern:tt,Color:1},{Pattern:mr,Color:11}]}}` It was definitely working for me.

Comment: that has unbalanced curly brackets,could it be because i am using Sphax pure bd texture pack?

Comment: it works in the deault texture pack

Comment: @Bounce01 I just noticed that the problem is caused by weird dotted square characters‌ with letter patterns like ZWNJ. I forgot that it happens sometimes when you copy and paste. Remove the characters, and the command should work.